# Google DataPrep is extremely slow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

In Google Dataflow, i have a job that basically looks like this:

Dataset: 100 rows, 1 column.
Recipe: 0 steps
Output: New Table.

But it takes between 6-8 minutes to run. What could be the issue?

Comment: For 100 rows Dataprep will give you the results for free and instantly through the web UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually times are in minutes, not in seconds for Dataprep/dataflow setup.
These solutions are for large data sets and the duration stays constant even if you have 10 times the size.

DataPrep creates for you a DataFlow workflow, and provisions a few VMs for you, that takes time, usually that phase could be in the minute mark. And only a bit later is scaling that up to 50 or 1000 boxes.

Comment: Thank you - very nice answer.

If there is a lot of "fixed cost" pr. dataflow, then it might make sense to do some larger flows, with more transformations. 

We are also testing out other solutions with crontab/airflow running some views.

Comment: This means that even if I have 10000x more data, it will still run the same time? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @JohnAndrews I don't have, but google the "tram challenge dataflow" it might be interest for you.

Comment: 10.6 billion rows within some stops for 0.85 USD.